# Mongoose: Validation not being executed when saving

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I've defined this Mongoose schema:

```
// validator function
var arrayWithAtLeastFiveElements = function (a) {
    return (a !== undefined && a.length >= 5);
};

var orderSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: User,
        required: true
    },
    products: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: Product,
        required: true,
        validate: [arrayWithAtLeastFiveElements, 'Order needs to have at least five products']
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
});
```

When I try to save it, the validation is not executed if `products` is `undefined`, `null` or an empty array, and it saves the new order with an empty array of products in each case. The validations are only run when `products` is an array with at least one element. Any clue what's going on? It there a way to make the validation run in all cases? Also, what does require do in this case? I don't see any change in validations if I define products array as required or not...

Comment: From my experience, don't depend on mongoose validation.

Comment: Try to define it like `products: { type: [Schema.ObjectId], required: true}`. Anyway, undefined is validated only with required validator. You can also write your own validator to validate array length and use it like `minlength: 5`. Still this validator won't cover undefined.

Comment: @Amiram Korach: Thanks! It works! But, how come? Now I have it all covered, if the array is empty, null or undefined required validates it, in other cases my custom valitor runs.

Comment: I just wrote how I always do it. I don't know if writing like you did is fine.

Comment: OK. By the way, the minlength validation is only for strings, I think

Comment: Sure, but you can write your own validator for minlength. It will look nicer.

Comment: ah, all right, didn't get that you were meaning a custom validator. Thanks for everything! :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I was wondering how would you define the 'minlength: 5' validator. I don't find anywhere how to pass arguments to your validator besides the field being validated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it with:

```
products: {
   type: [Schema.ObjectId],
   required: true,
}
```